# Save checkbox list value Sql database in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to store fields and checkboxes in a database table in a form: The connection table contains the following fields:

connection table:

```
public  partial class Connection
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CommunicationName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Register table:

```
public class RegisterForm
{
    #region Ctor
    public RegisterForm()
    {

    }
    #endregion Ctor

    #region Properties

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Required"))]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "This field must be a maximum of 50 characters")]
    [TypeConverter("NVarchar(121)")]
    [DisplayName("FullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<Connection> Communications { get; set; }   
}
```

The values of the checkbox fields in the list are displayed using the following method:

```
questionForm.Communications = db.Connections.ToList<Connection>();
```

Now how to save the information in the post and save it to the register table. ????????? What changes should be Create to the update, delete operation in the register?

controller for register:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,FullName,PhoneNumber,Email,Communication,")]RegisterForm questionForm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {             
        db.Registers.Add(questionForm);
        var data = db.SaveChanges();
            return View("FormSuccessfullySubmitted");              
    }
        return View(questionForm);
}
```

Comment: Where is your controller and DB functionalities? You just create domain model but no data access code here!!

Comment: also show us what you have done in terms of binding and trying to save

Answer (score 0):

You should read about MVC model binding. Normally it could bound it without any problem. But lists are slightly different. You are to provide index of item in list. That is why it is better to use **for**, instead of **foreach**.

Check this view and grab it POSTed values to examine. Pay attention, that all list items are displayed using its index in list.

```
<table class="table">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Bind", "Bind", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].CommunicationName)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].IsSelected)
             </td>
         </tr>
     }

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

</table>
```

Comment: When select value from checkboxes, how should I check that the information is recorded in the table register in the controller?????

Comment: What changes should be made to the controller to save the checkbox values ???

Comment: In other words, what changes should be made in order to save the selected values to the table  register??? Thank you for your guidance

Comment: You'll get property IsSelected set to true. Just create controller method, called Bind and debug which information is available